# Change page javascript code (TamperMonkey) to send keyboard strokes to the parent DOM

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tampermonkey, userscripts

I have a page that uses the TradingView widget, which you can type inside it any key on the keyboard to trigger a symbol search. I used Chrome's debugger to breakpoint and know exactly which line of code does that. I want the key event to be bubbled up to the general DOM to be handled by my own custom function.

How to do that? Any sample code would be appreciated. Here is the code snippet from TradingView ('t' is the key event):

```
            a || (o.handle = a = function(t) {
                return s === Te || t && Te.event.triggered === t.type ? s : Te.event.dispatch.apply(a.elem, arguments)
            }
```

So instead of the return statement I want to send that key event to my own function. The full TradingView code where this code is: https://static.bitmex.com/assets/tradingView/static/tv-chart.min-6ce28e05fd34b9cf06a4e63b29980a72.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than altering the page code (which is possible, but can be tedious), consider changing your own listener to run in the *capturing* phase, rather than the bubbling phase. Eg, instead of

```
document.body.addEventListener('keypress', fn);
```

do

```
document.body.addEventListener('keypress', fn, true);
```

and it'll run before the event has bubbled down to the inner element.

If the page's listener on the inner element needs to be complete before your `fn` runs, you can call `fn` after a small `setTimeout`:

```
document.body.addEventListener('keypress', () => setTimeout(fn), true);
```

If you also want to prevent the widget's code from running, make sure to call `stopPropagation` in your capturing listener so the event doesn't capture down to the widget:

```
const fn = (event) => {
  event.stopPropagation();
  // rest of code
};
```

If the container you're sending the key event to is inside an iframe, the parent window won't see the event at all, due to security issues.

On *most* pages, you'd be able to communicate the event up to the parent by using `postMessage`, eg:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name             0 New Userscript
// @include          https://www.bitmex.com/app/trade/XBTUSD
// @include          https://static.bitmex.com/chartEmbed*
// @grant            GM_getValue
// @run-at document-start
// ==/UserScript==

if (window.location.host === 'www.bitmex.com') {
  const mainFn = () => {
    console.log('b');
  };
  // We're on the top level
  const keydown = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (!e.altKey && e.key === 'b') {
      mainFn();
    }
  };
  window.addEventListener('keydown', keydown, true);
  window.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
    if (e.origin === 'https://static.bitmex.com' && e.data === 'keydown inside iframe') {
      mainFn();
    }
  });
} else {
  // We're in the iframe
  // When a keypress is detected, message the parent window
  const keydown = (e) => {
    console.log('iframe kd');
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (!e.altKey && e.key === 'b') {
      window.top.postMessage('keydown inside iframe', '*');
    }
  };
  window.addEventListener('click', keydown, true);
}
```

The `@run-at document-start` is needed because the iframe has a CSP which [forbids userscripts without it](https://github.com/Tampermonkey/tampermonkey/issues/593) from running.

But unfortunately, there's another problem: in this particular case, the iframe window *also* overwrites `EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener` on pageload, before the userscript has a chance to run. While you could *usually* use `// @run-at document-start` to ensure you save a reference to a variable before a page script overwrites it, this isn't possible in an iframe; Chrome userscripts in iframes *cannot* run at the very start of pageload.

Without a reference to `EventTarget.addEventListener` (or `EventTarget.prototype.onclick` or `EventTarget.prototype.onkeydown` setters, etc), there's no way to access the browser-level API that registers the user's actions.

I don't think what you're looking for is possible in Tampermonkey.

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work. It is still sending the key event to the widget instead of my listener.

Comment: Do you want to prevent the widget code from running completely? From the question, it sounded like you just wanted to ensure the event bubbled up to your listener

Comment: I want to prevent the widget code from getting any keyboard events and instead just sending them to the parent DOM.

Comment: I have my code inside $(window).bind("load", function() { CODE HERE })  
So I assume it is already loading after page and scripts finished loading.

Comment: If the page attaches a key listener, and you attach a key listener, it doesn't matter in which order the listeners are attached *unless* they're attached to the same element, which isn't occurring here. Just call `stopPropagation` to prevent the event from propagating downwards

Comment: I tried the event.stopPropagation(), it is still not working. If I click inside the widget and type a key, it is first capturing it and not bubbling up to the parent DOM.

Comment: That shouldn't occur, it sounds like the page script is *not* attaching an event to the inner element, or it's attaching a *different* event than the one you think it is (and that different event is preventing your userscript's listener from running). Can you post the page in question?

Comment: Sure. http://www.Bitmex.com  Then click the logo at the top to go to the chart page without login.

Comment: And here is my code snippet from the UserScript:

$(window).bind("load", function() {
    document.body.addEventListener('keydown', keydown, true);
});

    function keydown(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        if(!e.altKey && e.key === 'b') {... rest of the code

Comment: Works fine here. Replacing `rest of code` with `console.log('b')` results in: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHDJ9.png when I type anywhere on the page

Comment: Did you click inside the chart and try typing? That's where the issue happens.

Comment: See edit. It's in an iframe, so the event doesn't propagate to the parent window. You could usually add a listener inside the iframe to use `postMessage` to tell the parent, but here, the site has replaced `addEventListener` and other possibilities with their own custom function that blocks custom `addEventListener` etc calls - and `@run-at document-start` does not actually run at the very beginning of pageload in an iframe, so you can't save a reference to it. I don't think what you're looking for is possible